# Android Studio lauch Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-15

**Preconditions :**

- Installed Android Studio 2.0
- Installed Intellij Idea 15 on the same user in PC

**Problem :**

When I try to start Android studio 2.0 it lauhches Android Studio Logo and after few seconds it start Intellij Idea.

How I can fix this?

Comment: I just use IntelliJ IDEA for Android stuff. Works fine. P.S. version 15 isn't the latest

Comment: uninstall 1 of them since android studio is a child of intellij idea, also update your IDE, kind of unupdated